# Provide judgement on polkadot js

Tags: polkadot-js, pallet-identity

I'm trying to use my node's identity pallet via polkadot js. Generally that works well, but I do run into an issue when providing judgements.

This function requires an `identity: H256 (Hash)` value. This is the hash value of the identity info. The question is where I can find this on polkadot js?

I tried the extrinsic hash from the block produced after `set_identity`, but that's clearly not the right value, since it results in a `JudgementForDifferentIdentity` error.

Comment: i'm not familiar with this but this might be relevant https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage#identity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the Hash of the [identity info](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/identity/src/types.rs#L290C12-L290C24), which is an struct with the information of the account:

```rs
pub struct IdentityInfo<FieldLimit: Get<u32>> {
    pub additional: BoundedVec<(Data, Data), FieldLimit>,
    pub display: Data,
    pub legal: Data,
    pub web: Data,
    pub riot: Data,
    pub email: Data,
    pub pgp_fingerprint: Option<[u8; 20]>,
    pub image: Data,
    pub twitter: Data,
}
```

However keep in mind that to call the extrinsic `provide_judgement` you have to be a [Registrars](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-identity#requesting-a-judgement).
If you want to be a Registar check this: [Becoming a Registrar](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-guides-identity#becoming-a-registrar) and if you just want to request a judgment for your identity: [How to Request and Cancel Identity Judgement](https://support.polkadot.network/support/solutions/articles/65000181990-how-to-request-and-cancel-identity-judgement)

Comment: can you please me some link or info of how can i covert  struct into the valid hash as it is showing invalid identity

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not the transaction hash, just pre calculate the hash as following.
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ec6be6ed664f09098795a44cbe91c2d465662e9e/frame/identity/src/lib.rs#L763-L765